# The difference between `entry_SYSCALL64_slow_path` and `entry_SYSCALL64_fast_path`

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

We know that system call will call the function `entry_SYSCALL_64` in [entry_64.S](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/16f73eb02d7e1765ccab3d2018e0bd98eb93d973/arch/x86/entry/entry_64.S). When I read the source code, I find there are two different types of call after the prepartion of registers, one is `entry_SYSCALL64_slow_path` and the other is `entry_SYSCALL64_fast_path`. Can you tell the difference between the two functions?

Comment: It has to do with *ptrace*. If the process is traced or stepped or syscall-emulated Linux will save some extra regs and do the call to syscall handler [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/entry/common.c#L282). Otherwise, it just call the handler from the assembly code. I've never dug into the differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon entry in `entry_SYSCALL_64` Linux will:

1. Swap `gs` to get per-cpu parameters.
2. Set the stack from the parameters of above.
3. Disable the IRQs.
4. Create a **partial** `pt_regs` structure on the stack. This saves the caller context.
5. If the current task has `_TIF_WORK_SYSCALL_ENTRY` or `_TIF_ALLWORK_MASK` set, it *goes to the slow path*.
6. Enter the *fast path* otherwise.

`_TIF_WORK_SYSCALL_ENTRY` is defined [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6.13/source/arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h#L140) with a comment stating:

> ```
> /*
>  * work to do in syscall_trace_enter().  Also includes TIF_NOHZ for
>  * enter_from_user_mode()
>  */
> ```

`_TIF_ALLWORK_MASK` does not seems to be defined for x86, a definition for MIPS is [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6.13/source/arch/mips/include/asm/thread_info.h#L169) with a comment stating:

> ```
> /* work to do on any return to u-space */
> ```

## Fast path

Linux will:

1. Enable the IRQs.
2. Check if the syscall number is out of range (note the `pt_regs` struct was already created with `ENOSYS` for the value of `rax`).
3. Dispatch to the system call with an indirect jump.
4. Save the return value (`rax`) of the syscall into `rax` in the `pt_regs` on the stack.
5. Check again if `_TIF_ALLWORK_MASK` is set for the current task, if it is it will jump to the *slow return path*.
6. Restore the caller context and issue a `sysret`.

## Slow return path

1. Save the registers not saved before in `pt_regs` (`rbx`, `rbp`, `r12`-`r15`).
2. Call `syscall_return_slowpath`, defined [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/entry/common.c#L257).

Note that point 2 will end up calling `trace_sys_exit`.

## Slow path

1. Save the registers not saved before in `pt_regs` (see above)
2. Call `do_syscall_64`, defined [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/entry/common.c#L282).

Point 2 will call `syscall_trace_enter`.

---

So the slow vs fast path has to do with `ptrace`. I haven't dug into the code but I suppose the whole machinery is skipped if `ptrace` is not needed for the caller.
This is indeed an important optimization.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply, it's really clear. I have one more question, is there any convenient way to debug the code step by step to learn it more deeply?

Comment: @tyChen Yes, see [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/dev-tools/gdb-kernel-debugging.html). I've never done that, though. There are even graphical front-ends for GDB.